# Express $w$ and $1/w$ for $w=\frac {\sqrt2+\sqrt3}{\sqrt5-\sqrt3}$ in the simplest form with a rational denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, fractions, rationalising-denominator

If $w = \frac {\sqrt2+\sqrt3}{\sqrt5-\sqrt3} $

Express the following in the simplest form (with a rational denominator)

i) $w$

ii) $\frac1w$

I'm confused about (ii) question :/ pls help me.

Comment: Part (ii) asks you to do for $\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}$, which is $\frac{1}{w}$, the same sort of thing that you did for $w$ in Part (i).

Answer (score 2):

If $w = \frac {\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3}{\sqrt 5-\sqrt 3}$, then $\frac 1w=\frac {\sqrt 5-\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3}$  If you can do i, you should be able to do ii.  The process is the same.

Answer (score 0):

$w=\frac {\sqrt2+\sqrt3}{\sqrt5-\sqrt3}\frac {\sqrt5+\sqrt3}{\sqrt5+\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt10 + \sqrt15-\sqrt6-9}{16}$

$\frac{1}{w}=\frac {\sqrt5-\sqrt3}{\sqrt2+\sqrt3}\frac {\sqrt2-\sqrt3}{\sqrt2-\sqrt3}=\frac{-\sqrt10 - \sqrt15+\sqrt6+9}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
 w &=\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}} \\
   &=\frac{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3})}
          {(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3})} \\
   &=\frac{3+\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{15}}{5-3} \\
   &=\frac{1}{2} (3+\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{15}) \\
 \frac{1}{w} &=\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}} \\
   &=\frac{(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})}
          {(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})} \\
   &=\frac{\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{6}-3}{3-2} \\
   &=\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{6}-3
\end{align*}